# I can't access my old account that used myopenid

Tags: support, myopenid

I didn't get the memo regarding myopenid shutting down. As a consequence I cannot log in to my account anymore. Is there a way I can recover ? I tried doing it with this account, using the same email I had on myopenid but it didn't work. My myopenid url was jfoucher.myopenid.com

How can I log back in to my old account, or merge it with this new one ?